# link.exe returns error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\Program.obj'

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, linker, linker-errors

I'm compiling with a Batch file containing

```
@echo off

set link=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\link

"%link%" external_input.obj periodic_dinger.obj flagger.obj monitor.obj main.obj libGui.lib libCore.lib libCint.lib libRIO.lib libNet.lib libHist.lib libGraf.lib libGraf3D.lib libGpad.lib libTree.lib libRint.lib libPostscript.lib libMatrix.lib libPhysics.lib libMathCore.lib libThread.lib
```

All the objects and libraries are in the same directory, which is the directory I'm executing the Batch file from, and also where the Batch file is located. I've tried adding the current directory to `/LIBPATH:`, but no luck. My `LIB` environment variable is

```
C:\Users\jroth\Data\online_monitor_v.0.5>echo %LIB%
"C:\Program Files\ (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\LIB";"C:\Program Files
(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Window
s Kits\8.0\lib\win8\um\x86";
```

I made sure that everything was quoted. The same error came up when everything was unquoted. The error verbatim is

```
C:\Users\jroth\Data\online_monitor_v.0.5>make
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 11.00.50727.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\link
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\Program.obj'
```

`make.bat` is the name of the batch file I'm using to link this, not a makefile.

I'm running `vcvarsall.bat` before doing any of this.

Comment: Not sure, but what if you try putting the path in quotes too? `set link="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\link"`

Comment: When I remove the quotes around `"%link%"`, it gives me `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\link"
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\link.obj'`. When I leave the quotes, it says that that's a bad idea.

Comment: Try `set link="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\link"`. You need quotes as the linker only takes paths without whitespaces if not quoted. So it results in adding an ".obj" right before the first space

Comment: Is that different from what @Mr Lister recommended?

Comment: Oh i did just saw quotes and what you tried. So it's the same yes

Comment: That did it! I needed to delete the old `link` variable first, but using `set _link=<stuff>` after that did it. The executable isn't working, but that's likely unrelated to this issue. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with the environment variable `link` that you used. The MS linker also uses this variable for flags.

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y6t9esh.aspx:

> The LINK tool uses the following environment variables:
>
> - LINK, if defined. The LINK tool processes options and arguments defined in the LINK environment variable before processing the command line.

So you can't use `set link=...`, you'll have to use another name. `_link` will do fine.

Comment: The given link to MSDN isn't working anymore. I believe this is a workable link the same article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linking?view=msvc-170